# Force open dropdown onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I would open a dropdown when i click in a input text. So, the behaviour should be the same of a button to open it. I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/45/)

and this is the code i use:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="uk-width-1-1" ng-controller="TestCtrl">        
      <form id="form" class="uk-form uk-width-1-1 center-form">
          <div class="uk-button-group uk-width-1-2 uk-vertical-align-middle">

              <!-- This is a button -->
              <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="text" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-vertical-align-middle">

                  <!-- This is the container enabling the JavaScript -->
                  <div data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click', justify:'#input'}">

                      <!-- This is the button toggling the dropdown -->
                      <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle!important;" class="uk-button"><i class="uk-icon-caret-down"></i></a>

                      <!-- This is the dropdown -->
                      <div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-small">
                          <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown" ng-repeat="item in items">
                              <li><a href="">{{item}}</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>

                  </div>
           </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried some angular but it's not working

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.items=['menu item 1','menu item 2'];

    $scope.itemClicked = function(item, event, index){

    }

    $(document).on('click', '.uk-dropdown', function() {
        $(this).parents('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').removeClass('uk-open');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#input', function() {
        $(this).parents('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').addClass('uk-open');
    });
});
```

of course when you write in the input, if the dropdown is open, it must not close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` inside the `#input` handler is not what you are thinking. You can use `.uk-dropdown`. And `focus` should be used for `textbox`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.uk-dropdown', function () {
    $(this).closest('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').removeClass('uk-open');
});

$(document).on('focus', '#input', function () {
    $('.uk-dropdown').closest('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').addClass('uk-open');
}).on('blur', '#input', function() {
    $('.uk-dropdown').closest('[data-uk-dropdown]:first').removeClass('uk-open');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8y48q/49/

Comment: @End.Game Some issue with jsfiddle. Please copy-paste above code and check

Comment: Yes it is jsfiddle.. by the way, it is working when i click over the input, but it should disappear when i click off of it. And to be more "an angular way", is it possible create a directive that do this?

Comment: Yes! It is working! amazing. Only one more thing about the directive.. is it possible put the code in it? create a directive with this code

Comment: @End.Game Don't know about Angular.js

Comment: ok no problem..seems works well..there is only one more little problem..if i open the dropdown from button i can "use" the items inside it..instead if it opens from input it close when i click over it.. this is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/50/ i added input text inside the dropdown